# Wordpress custom load more button for different table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have table of wp_details in which i have 1000 rows of data to show . I want to show only 10 on front page after clicking load more I further want to show 10 more and so on . I have tried to create custom load more but not working and i am stucked

**ajax.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_loadmore','my_loadmore');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_loadmore','my_loadmore');

function my_loadmore(){

    $paged=$_POST['page'];
    echo $paged;
    die();
}
```

**myjs.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
jQuery(document).on('click','.myLoad',function(){
    var page=$(this).data('page');
    var ajaxurl=$(this).data('url');
    jQuery.ajax({    
        url:ajaxurl,
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            page:page,
            action:"my_loadmore"
        },
        error:function(response){
          console.log("error");  
        },
        success:function(){
           jQuery('.et_pb_post').append("Running");
        }
    });
```

this is my **index.php** page of my template where i am loading the data from SQL table

```
<article>
<?php

$table_name="wpnn_details";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name"); 
if(!empty($results))                        
{
foreach($results as $row){
?>

<p class="description">
<?php echo $row->description;?>
</p>

</article>

<?php       }   } ?>

<div>
    <button class="myLoad" data-page="1" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>">Load More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Am on my phone and have no dev stack to test this but here's an sort of example you can try to imlement.

Update your function from ajax.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_loadmore','my_loadmore');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_loadmore','my_loadmore');

function my_loadmore(){
    global $wpdb;

    $paged=$_POST['page']*10;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name LIMIT 10 OFFSET $paged");

}
```

edit the button underneath as follows:
Paginate will indicate the current pagination, starting from offset 0.

```
<button class="myLoad" data-page="0" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>">Load More</button>
```

Inside your myjs.js
Update the ajax call:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.myLoad',function(){
    var page=parseInt($(this).data('page'));
    var ajaxurl=$(this).data('url');
    jQuery.ajax({    
        url:ajaxurl,
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            page:page,
            action:"my_loadmore"
        },
        error:function(response){
          console.log("error");  
        },
        success:function(data){
           if (data !== undefined ){ 
               jQuery('button.myLoad').data('page',(page+1));
               jQuery('#mycontentdiv").append(response);
           } else {
               jQuery('button.myLoad').remove();
           } 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it is appending nothing to the div

Comment: it is only appending 0 inside the div